# How to call stored queries of Ms Access with parameters

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, ms-access-2007

I added a stored query in MS Access to insert the data in a table with the parameters while creating the database.

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE queryAddAcc(AccNum text(50), AccName Text(50), By long, Date Date) AS 
INSERT INTO tableAccounts (AccNumber, AccountName, By, Date)
VALUES ([AccNum], [AccName], [By], [Date])";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please tell How to call the stored query to insert values on "Save" button click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would absolutely change those reserved words in a more neutral way. I mean By and Date are reserved words for access and thus require squared brackets around them, but in your context there is no reason to call those parameters in that way

```
cmmd.CommandText = @"CREATE PROCEDURE queryAddAcc(AccNum text(50), AccName Text(50), 
                     ByParam long, DateParam Date) AS 
                   INSERT INTO tableAccounts (AccNumber, AccountName, [By], [Date])
                   VALUES ([AccNum], [AccName], [ByParam], [DateParam])";
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course I suggest to change also the field's names for the same reason. I am sure that if I were you I would forget everytime

Next, to call the query, you need only to

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("queryAddAcc", connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("AccNum", valueForAccNum);
..... add the other parameters here .....
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that you need to add the parameter in the exact order expected by the stored procedure because OleDb won't make efforts to recognize your parameters by their name and assign the values in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I changed reserved words. while executing I got an exception that "Too few parameters, expected 5". But in the stored query there are only 4 parameters. In the table are 5 columns. AccId is auto Increment column. Do I need to pass it as parameter ?

Comment: No you don't pass the autoincrement column value in Access. If you get that error is possible that some field name is not recognized and thus the engine thinks it is a parameter.